# How do I get the UpgradeCode for an installed MSI program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have installed a program on my computer. How can I get the `UpgradeCode` for this program?
The program is an MSI created in Visual Studio 2010.
[image]

Comment: That image is too small to read. Please provide the information as text.

Comment: You're going to need to add a larger image.

Comment: on screen UpgradeCode in msi setup project in VS 2010.i need to get it for installed program

Comment: I don't understand the context of your question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok. Program istalled using MSI have 2 guids ProductCode and UpgradeCode(on screen in MSI Setup project). This guids installer use for upgrade and uninstal program(more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa372399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I can find ProductCode in Window Register when program installed, but i dont know how i can find UpgradeCode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the MSI available, open it up with e.g. Orca, and check the Property table.

EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx

another alternative is InstEdit http://www.instedit.com/

Comment: What is 'Orca'?Can you post link on description?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the **product code** and **upgrade code** for installed MSI files, you can try these two answers:

Finding the product code:
**[How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)** (PowerShell).

Finding the upgrade code:
**[How can I find the Upgrade Code for an installed MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/46637095#46637095)** (VBScript).